# How to get one output for several timestep in Keras LSTM?

Tags: python, keras, lstm

I want to classifying a timeframe of data. So for example every 5 input, there's one output. But my code refuse to accept my output.

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(GRU(32, input_shape=(TimeStep.TIME_STEP + 1, 10), return_sequences=True, activation='relu'))
model.add(GRU(64, activation='relu', return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dense(2, activation='hard_sigmoid'))

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=[categorical_accuracy])
history = model.fit(TimeStep.fodder, TimeStep.target, epochs=50)
```

The error:

```
ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_1 to have shape (5, 2) but got array with shape (31057, 2)
```

It does have 31057 data point that each data point consist of 5 sequential data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `return_sequences` param in the GRU layer instructs the model to return the state at each time step rather than the final activation.

If you set that flag to False in the second GRU, your model will return the shape that you expect.
Tip: use `model.summary()` to display the output shapes of your layers.

For a model with a categorical loss you want the output layer activation to be a softmax not a sigmoid.